# differentiate this power series expression $n$ times

Tags: derivatives, power-series

> Given $V(R) = k_0 + k_1 (R-R_e) + \frac{1}{2!} k_2 (R-R_e)^2 + ... = \sum_{n=0} \frac{k_n}{n!} (R-R_e)^n$

I am trying to show that $k_n = d^nV/dR^n = n! k_n$ when evaluated at $R=R_e$

How do I show this? I understand that $n! = n(n-1)(n-2) ...$

$\frac{d}{dR} = n \frac{k_n}{n!} (R-Re)^{n-1}$

If I do more derivatives, the $n$ and $n!$ cancels out each other and when evaluated at $R=R_e$, I get $k_n$, how do I get $n!k_n$ ?

Comment: The $k_n$ you got is the correct answer, not $n!k_n.$

Comment: You have $k_n = n!k_n$ in your post. The only ways that could possibly be true is if $n = 0, n=1$, or $k_n = 0$. It seems pretty clear that this was not what was intended. But whether this was an error in your source, or in your copying of it here, I cannot say.